# Grid Layout is not showing buttons or anything that I add to it in the design mode

Tags: android-layout, android-gridlayout

[The button is the blue square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Byu.png)

I'm adding `GridLayout` in a layout file of the project. After that, if I add anything in the layout it goes to the corner and when I'm testing everything is in place!

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sumTxtView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="31+12"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pointsTxtView"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/timerTxtView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.103" />

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/theGridLayout"
    android:layout_width="323dp"
    android:layout_height="441dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.523"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="3" />
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Any idea what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code, how should we help you without seeing your code?

Comment: i did add them please check

Comment: thank you i found the solution. just remove Backwards Compatibility mark while making the project